# If and Else Condition to Separate into Different Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to figure out how to separate the code below so that:

```
if Me.impactCombobox.Value = "High" then
Private Sub enterButton_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("HI Project Database")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

'check for fields to have values
If Trim(Me.nameTextbox.Value) = "" Then
    Me.nameTextbox.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter your name"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.projectTextbox.Value) = "" Then
  Me.projectTextbox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please enter a Project Name"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.audienceCombobox.ListIndex) = -1 Then
    Me.audienceCombobox.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please select an Audience"
    Exit Sub
End If


'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
  '.Unprotect Password:="password"
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.nameTextbox.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.projectTextbox.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.audienceCombobox.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.impactCombobox.Value
  Dim MonthNumber  As Byte
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer: ColumnNumber = 4

    For MonthNumber = 0 To 11
        If audienceListbox.Selected(MonthNumber) Then
            .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "No"
        End If
        'Increase the column Index for each time through the loop
        ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
    Next

End With


MsgBox "Project Entered Successfully"


'clear the data
Me.nameTextbox.Value = ""
Me.projectTextbox.Value = ""
Me.nameTextbox.SetFocus
Me.audienceCombobox.Value = Null
Me.impactCombobox.Value = Null
Me.q1Checkbox.Value = False
Me.q2Checkbox.Value = False
Me.q3Checkbox.Value = False
Me.q4Checkbox.Value = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = audienceListbox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If audienceListbox.Selected(i) = True Then
        audienceListbox.Selected(i) = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

or

Else if the me.impactCombobox.Value = "Low" then it would put it in the "LI Project Database" sheet (with the same requirements).

When I tried to do it, it said I had a bunch of duplicates. I'm new to VBA (started a day ago) so any guidance would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you just copying the entire code for the else me.impactCombobox.Value = "Low" ? If so you might be running into an issue where you can't DIM the same variable twice in the same sub routine.

Comment: Yes that is what I was doing, would a solution to be to remove the variables or would I have to rename them then change the variables in the code above to match?

Comment: You'd actually be able to just remove the DIM statements (only DIM once.), but my suggestion would be to change the variable names to more descriptive terms like wsLow and wsHigh and DIM both of them. Up to you!

Comment: I just renamed all the DIM statements in trying and it works (for now) might not be efficient but does the job for the time being. Might go back and try and just removing the dim statements and see how that goes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: post a new question with your new code and its issues. This will also reach much more people and increase your possibilities of getting help

Comment: @user3598756 I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968996/code-fluency-errorchecking-click-unclick-pulling-new-values if you can lend a helping hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a possible refactoring to (hopefully) make you code flexible and maintainable:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub enterButton_Click()
    If Not CheckInputs Then Exit Sub 'check for fields to have values
    Process GetWs(Me.impactCombobox.Value) ' process data passing the proper worksheet got from GetWs() function
    MsgBox "Project Entered Successfully"
    ClearUFData 'clear the data
End Sub


Private Sub Process(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim MonthNumber  As Byte
    Dim ColumnNumber As Long: ColumnNumber = 4

    'find first empty row in database
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    'copy the data to the database
    'use protect and unprotect lines,
    '     with your password
    '     if worksheet is protected

    With ws
        '.Unprotect Password:="password"
        .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.nameTextbox.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.projectTextbox.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.audienceCombobox.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.impactCombobox.Value

        For MonthNumber = 0 To 11
            If audienceListbox.Selected(MonthNumber) Then
                .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "No"
            End If
            'Increase the column Index for each time through the loop
            ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
        Next MonthNumber
    End With

End Sub


Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    CheckInputs = True
End Function


Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function


Function GetWs(impact As String) As Worksheet
    Select Case impact
        Case "High"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Project Database")
        Case "Low"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Project Database")
'        Case Else
    End Select
End Function


Sub ClearUFData()
    Dim i As Integer
   'clear the data
    Me.nameTextbox.Value = ""
    Me.projectTextbox.Value = ""
    Me.nameTextbox.SetFocus
    Me.audienceCombobox.Value = Null
    Me.impactCombobox.Value = Null
    Me.q1Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q2Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q3Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q4Checkbox.Value = False
    For i = audienceListbox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If audienceListbox.Selected(i) = True Then
            audienceListbox.Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a very beautiful set of code, thank you so much. I've implemented it and will be using it as a reference for proper declarations!

Comment: you are welcome. please consider the following coding logic issues: 1) separate specific tasks and wrap them into a proper function or sub 2) have variables declared only where they're needed for the specific task 3) have tasks carried over only when really needed

Comment: So I'm also adding in another listbox named lengthListbox2, and it's an exact copy of the prior lengthListbox but it's for 2017 year and it's column starts at 16, would this work? http://pastebin.com/FsPq2i5t -- Doesn't seem to work so far, not sure how I would go about doing another replication

Comment: Also how would I go about doing checkcontrols for listboxes? Making sure they check at least 1 of the boxes