# Code Fluency - ErrorChecking, Click/Unclick, Pulling New Values

Tags: vba, excel

So here is my initial code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub clearButton_Click()
ClearUFData 'clears the form
End Sub


Private Sub enterButton_Click()
    If Not CheckInputs Then Exit Sub 'check for fields to have values
    Process GetWs(Me.impactCombobox.Value) ' process data passing the proper worksheet got from GetWs() function
    MsgBox "Project Entered Successfully"
    ClearUFData 'clear the data
End Sub

Private Sub Process(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim MonthNumber As Byte
    Dim ColumnNumber As Long: ColumnNumber = 4

    'find first empty row in database
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

    'copy the data to the database
    'use protect and unprotect lines,
    '     with your password
    '     if worksheet is protected

    With ws
        '.Unprotect Password:="password"
        .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.nameTextbox.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.projectTextbox.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.audienceCombobox.Value
        For MonthNumber = 0 To 11
            If lengthListbox.Selected(MonthNumber) Then
                .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                .Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "No"
            End If

            'Increase the column Index for each time through the loop
            ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1

        Next MonthNumber
        If rvpCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 28).Value = "RVP"
        End If
        If uwCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 29).Value = "UW"
        End If
        If uaCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 30).Value = "UA"
        End If
        If umCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 31).Value = "UM"
        End If
        If baCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 32).Value = "BA"
        End If
        If otherCheckbox.Value = True Then
            .Cells(iRow, 33).Value = "Other"
        End If

    End With

End Sub

Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    CheckInputs = True
End Function

Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function

Function GetWs(impact As String) As Worksheet
    Select Case impact
        Case "High"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("HI Project Database")
        Case "Low"
            Set GetWs = Worksheets("LI Project Database")
'        Case Else
    End Select
End Function

Sub ClearUFData()
    Dim i As Integer
   'clear the data
    Me.nameTextbox.Value = ""
    Me.projectTextbox.Value = ""
    Me.nameTextbox.SetFocus
    Me.audienceCombobox.Value = Null
    Me.impactCombobox.Value = Null
    Me.q1Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q2Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q3Checkbox.Value = False
    Me.q4Checkbox.Value = False
    For i = lengthListbox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If lengthListbox.Selected(i) = True Then
            lengthListbox.Selected(i) = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub exitButton_Click()
' exits the form
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub q1Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(0) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(1) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(2) = True
If q1Checkbox.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox.Selected(0) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(1) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(2) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q2Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(3) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(4) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(5) = True
If q2Checkbox.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox.Selected(3) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(4) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(5) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q3Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(6) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(7) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(8) = True
If q3Checkbox.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox.Selected(6) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(7) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(8) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q4Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(9) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(10) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(11) = True
If q4Checkbox.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox.Selected(9) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(10) = False
    lengthListbox.Selected(11) = False
End If
End Sub
Private Sub q1Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(0) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(1) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(2) = True
If q1Checkbox2.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox2.Selected(0) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(1) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(2) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q2Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(3) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(4) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(5) = True
If q2Checkbox2.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox2.Selected(3) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(4) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(5) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q3Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(6) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(7) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(8) = True
If q3Checkbox2.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox2.Selected(6) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(7) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(8) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub q4Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(9) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(10) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(11) = True
If q4Checkbox2.Value = False Then
    lengthListbox2.Selected(9) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(10) = False
    lengthListbox2.Selected(11) = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' sets name textbox to focus on load and loads combobox list
nameTextbox.SetFocus
audienceCombobox.AddItem "HR Activities/Initiatives"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "BI Underwriting"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "Product Management"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "CI Operations"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "UW Systems"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "Regional Initiatives"
audienceCombobox.AddItem "Other"
lengthListbox.AddItem "January"
lengthListbox.AddItem "February"
lengthListbox.AddItem "March"
lengthListbox.AddItem "April"
lengthListbox.AddItem "May"
lengthListbox.AddItem "June"
lengthListbox.AddItem "July"
lengthListbox.AddItem "August"
lengthListbox.AddItem "September"
lengthListbox.AddItem "October"
lengthListbox.AddItem "November"
lengthListbox.AddItem "December"
'New Year
lengthListbox2.AddItem "January"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "February"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "March"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "April"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "May"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "June"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "July"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "August"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "September"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "October"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "November"
lengthListbox2.AddItem "December"
impactCombobox.AddItem "High"
impactCombobox.AddItem "Low"
End Sub
```

Now, some specific areas I need to address are that I just added in a new lengthListbox2 that is an exact replica and does everything lengthListbox does, it just starts the data starting from ColumnNumber = 16 but I can't figure how to adjust the DIMs to address this.

I am also trying to figure out the proper way to error check the q1-q4 checkboxes and the lengthListbox(2) so that they have to have clicked either one of the q1-q4 boxes or one of the options in the lengthListbox.

Also another small addition I'm trying to add is that if they click the first 3 properties in the listbox (months) q1 is checked, and the next 3 then q2 is selected. Right now my code only does vice versa, if Q1 is selected then it selects the first 3 months.

Excuse the messiness in some areas, I've had a lot of help putting the code together for fluency in certain areas and my newbie skills did the rest.

EDIT: 
Project length is now trying to pull a requirement from both current and next year when it just needs to be one or the other.

I've tried using this by setting up another control check but for lists specifically and separating two controlcheck situations but I need more so an or statement in there:

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControlList(Me.lengthListbox, Me.lengthListbox2, "Please Select Project Length") Then Exit Function

    CheckInputs = True
End Function

Private Function CountSelectedListBoxItems(lb As MSForms.ListBox) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then CountSelectedListBoxItems = CountSelectedListBoxItems + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Function CheckControlList(ctrl As MSForms.Control, ctrl2 As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "ListBox" '<--| add the case of a ListBox control passed to check
            CheckControlList = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0 '<--| call new function to check listboxes
'        Case Else
    End Select
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl2)
        Case "ListBox" '<--| add the case of a ListBox control passed to check
            CheckControlList = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0 '<--| call new function to check listboxes
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControlList Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function

Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox" '<--| add the case of a ListBox control passed to check
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0 '<--| call new function to check listboxes
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

I've tried using an OR statement to separate the two as well but it just ends up displaying "Please enter Project Length" prior to saying it was successfully entered:

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not (CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox) Or (CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2)) Then MsgBox "Please Enter Project Length": Exit Function

    CheckInputs = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to process two listboxes in a similar way but with some different parameters add a `ProcessListBox()` sub to handle a `ListBox` control processing, and specify as its parameters those that can change, like:

```
Sub ProcessListBox(lb As msforms.ListBox, ws As Worksheet, iRow As Long, ByVal iniCol As Long)
    Dim MonthNumber As Byte

    With ws
        For MonthNumber = 0 To 11
            If lb.Selected(MonthNumber) Then
                .Cells(iRow, iniCol).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                .Cells(iRow, iniCol).Value = "No"
            End If
            iniCol = iniCol + 1 'Increase the column Index for each time through the loop
        Next MonthNumber
    End With
End Sub
```

so that your processing "core" of `Process()` sub would be:

```
With ws
    '.Unprotect Password:="password"
    .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.nameTextbox.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.projectTextbox.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.audienceCombobox.Value

    If rvpCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 28).Value = "RVP"
    If uwCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 29).Value = "UW"
    If uaCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 30).Value = "UA"
    If umCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 31).Value = "UM"
    If baCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 32).Value = "BA"
    If otherCheckbox Then .Cells(iRow, 33).Value = "Other"
End With

ProcessListBox lengthListbox, ws, iRow, 4 '<--| process lengthListbox passing "4" as starting column
ProcessListBox lengthListbox2, ws, iRow, 16 '<--| process lengthListbox2 passing "16" as starting column
```

as for the listboxes and corresponding checkboxes cross checking, since you actually only care about the former, just check listboxes for any selected value

and you could that by means of a specific Function like:

```
Private Function CountSelectedListBoxItems(lb As msforms.ListBox) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then CountSelectedListBoxItems = CountSelectedListBoxItems + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

to add to your `CheckControl()` function `Case` block:

```
Function CheckControl(ctrl As msforms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox" '<--| add the case of a ListBox control passed to check
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0 '<--| call new function to check listboxes
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

and therefore update your `CheckInputs()` function

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox, "Please select a current year month") Then Exit Function '<--| check "lengthListbox"
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2, "Please select a next year month") Then Exit Function '<--| check "lengthListbox2"

    CheckInputs = True
End Function
```

---

I also think you need to update your `ClearUFData()` sub to handle both `lengthListbox` and `lengthListbox2`. and qXCheckbox2, too...

```
Sub ClearUFData()
    'clear the data
    With Me
        .nameTextbox.Value = ""
        .projectTextbox.Value = ""
        .nameTextbox.SetFocus
        .audienceCombobox.Value = Null
        .impactCombobox.Value = Null
        .q1Checkbox.Value = False
        .q2Checkbox.Value = False
        .q3Checkbox.Value = False
        .q4Checkbox.Value = False
        .q1Checkbox2.Value = False '<-- uncheck q1Checkbox2
        .q2Checkbox2.Value = False '<-- uncheck q2Checkbox2
        .q3Checkbox2.Value = False '<-- uncheck q3Checkbox2
        .q4Checkbox2.Value = False '<-- uncheck q4Checkbox2
        DeselectListBox lengthListbox '<-- deselect all listbox items
        DeselectListBox lengthListbox2 '<-- deselect all lkistbox items
    End With
End Sub
```

where I'd use a `DeselectListBox()` sub like follows:

```
Private Sub DeselectListBox(lb As msforms.ListBox)
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(i) = False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Finally some little improvements

`checkbox` control default property is `Value` that returns True or False whether it is checked or not

so instead of

```
If q1Checkbox.Value = False Then
```

you can simply use

```
If Not q1Checkbox Then
```

and the likes

this can have you simplify and shorten the following code:

```
Private Sub q1Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(0) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(1) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(2) = True
    If Not q1Checkbox Then
        lengthListbox.Selected(0) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(1) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(2) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q2Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(3) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(4) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(5) = True
    If Not q2Checkbox Then
        lengthListbox.Selected(3) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(4) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(5) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q3Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(6) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(7) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(8) = True
    If Not q3Checkbox Then
        lengthListbox.Selected(6) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(7) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(8) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q4Checkbox_Click()
    lengthListbox.Selected(9) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(10) = True
    lengthListbox.Selected(11) = True
    If Not q4Checkbox Then
        lengthListbox.Selected(9) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(10) = False
        lengthListbox.Selected(11) = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub q1Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(0) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(1) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(2) = True
    If Not q1Checkbox2 Then
        lengthListbox2.Selected(0) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(1) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(2) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q2Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(3) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(4) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(5) = True
    If q2Checkbox2.Value = False Then
        lengthListbox2.Selected(3) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(4) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(5) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q3Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(6) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(7) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(8) = True
    If Not q3Checkbox2 Then
        lengthListbox2.Selected(6) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(7) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(8) = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub q4Checkbox2_Click()
    lengthListbox2.Selected(9) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(10) = True
    lengthListbox2.Selected(11) = True
    If Not q4Checkbox2 Then
        lengthListbox2.Selected(9) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(10) = False
        lengthListbox2.Selected(11) = False
    End If
End Sub
```

UserForm_Initialize can be also made more "codeable" and readable with the use of `With` statement as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' sets name textbox to focus on load and loads combobox list
    nameTextbox.SetFocus

    With audienceCombobox
        .AddItem "HR Activities/Initiatives"
        .AddItem "BI Underwriting"
        .AddItem "Product Management"
        .AddItem "CI Operations"
        .AddItem "UW Systems"
        .AddItem "Regional Initiatives"
        .AddItem "Other"
    End With

    With lengthListbox
        .AddItem "January"
        .AddItem "February"
        .AddItem "March"
        .AddItem "April"
        .AddItem "May"
        .AddItem "June"
        .AddItem "July"
        .AddItem "August"
        .AddItem "September"
        .AddItem "October"
        .AddItem "November"
        .AddItem "December"
    End With

    'New Year
    With lengthListbox2
        .AddItem "January"
        .AddItem "February"
        .AddItem "March"
        .AddItem "April"
        .AddItem "May"
        .AddItem "June"
        .AddItem "July"
        .AddItem "August"
        .AddItem "September"
        .AddItem "October"
        .AddItem "November"
        .AddItem "December"
    End With

    With impactCombobox
        .AddItem "High"
        .AddItem "Low"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, do you know where I would go about changing it so that they would only need to select a month from the current year or the next year and not both? As of right now, if they select a month in the next year, it requires them to choose a month for the current year.

Comment: well, let's see some proposals from you. study the code, step through it and see what it actually does. then make changes and see the results. and if there are issues then come back with them

Comment: I've added some versions I've tried to run in my original post.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, I editted my original question trying to make a new control errror checking as well as trying an OR statement. Might just be clueless when it comes to the syntax in VBA in comparison with SQL and C#